# Install python module on remote server

Tags: python, remote-server, python-module, configparser

I have a internal scheduler tool which runs a python script on a remote server. I am using `configparser` module within my script. When I run this script through the tool it gives me below error.

```
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

I don't have access to that remote server so I can't just login to server and install required module.

Is there any way through which I can install configparser module by running any installation script on remote server through the tool ( I can neither download package on remote server nor run any commands, All I can do is, running scripts through this tool.) Please let me know if you need more clarification on this.

Comment: no way you have to have credentials

Comment: That module is [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) anyway, there is no need to install it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman …but it has been renamed from Python 2 to Python 3 and that might be the problem. Ankur should check if he is using the same Python version von all systems.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do something like this. Create a python script that calls a bash script to do what you want:

install.py:

```
import subprocess

script = """
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
pip install AnyPackage
"""

subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', script])
```

I am assuming you are using a virtualenv. If not, I assume the account that the script-runner uses has sudo access.